# Where is mod folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have got new Computer, and I need mods folder. I look at %appdata% .minecraft but folder mods was not there. What to do ?

Comment: @twobugs The asker has established where the .minecraft folder is, but cannot find a *mods* folder.

Comment: From my understanding, the same technique can be used to locate your *mods* folder. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @twobugs That in itself isn't, but the asker has already identified where the .minecraft folder is and where their mods folder should be (when it isn't there).

Comment: This is clearly not a duplicate and should not have been closed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'mods' folder. You need to find out how to install mods with your modloader. Ex: MC Forge. Run the installer and create the mods folder.

Comment: Actually, the mod folder will show up itself when you install forge. But that isn't the same for most others, so this is still correct.

Comment: And what to do now ?

Comment: run MC first. Then it should appear. Don't forget to select forge

Comment: I repair it :-D I just create new folder with name "mods"...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have installed forge for a mod folder to show up. You can get forge at the official website: http://files.minecraftforge.net

Comment: Yea, i do that. But "mods" isn´t there...